# refactoring async socket programming in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, delegates

I have a bunch of async methods that I want to expose via C# sockets. The general pattern in the MSDN [documentaions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) Has the following form:

```
 public static void StartListening()
 {
   ...
   IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
   ...
   listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener); 
   ... 
 }

 public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
    ...
    handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
 }

 public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 { 
    ...
    StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    ...
    CalculateResult(state);  
    ...
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                         new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
    ...
 }
```

So writing all this in a nice and clean form without repetition of code has been a challenge. I am thinking along these lines but have not been able to connect the dots:

```
    public static void StartListeningMaster()
    {
        string ipAddress = "localhost";
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        IPAddress address = ipHost.AddressList[0];

        StartListening(50000, address, AcceptCallback1);
        StartListening(50001, address, AcceptCallback2);
        StartListening(50002, address, AcceptCallback3);
        ...
    }
    
    public static void StartListening(int port, IPAddress ipAddress,  
                           Action<IAsyncResult> acceptCallback) {...}
    public static void AcceptCallback1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
       ...
       handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 
                         0, new AsyncCallback1(ReadCallback1), state);  
    }
    ...
```

This works fine up to this point. But to refactor it properly I would like to have one AcceptCallback method that takes as its parameter a generic ReadCallback that takes as its parameter a CalculateResult method. This way I would not have any repetition of code. However, if I modify my AcceptCallback method to take any more parameters than IAsyncResult (for example something like:

```
  public static void StartListening(int port, IPAddress ipAddress, Action<IAsyncResult, Action<IAsyncResult>> acceptCallback) {...}

  public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar, Action<IAsyncResult> readCallback) {}
```

I break the AsyncCallback delegate contract.

```
public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
```

Then I looked into extending the existing interfaces to allow the functionality. I looked into extending

```
public interface IAsyncResult
```

But that does not seem to be the right approach either. So, how do I write this code so I do not copy and paste pretty much the same code all over the place?

Comment: Just a heads up, you never call the `End...` methods. For example, in `AcceptCallback` you never call `listener.EndAccept(ar)`. Or do you, but you aren't showing it?

Answer (score 3):

So the way I tackle this is by moving the basic components in to their own abstract objects. Then build upon those objects. For example, the server only needs to accept/track connections. So I would make a server object that looks something like this:

```
namespace MultiServerExample.Base
{
    public interface IAsyncServerBase
    {
        void StartListening();
        bool IsListening { get; }
        void StopListening();
        void WriteDataToAllClients(byte[] data);
    }

    public abstract class AsyncServerBase<TClientBase> : IAsyncServerBase
        where TClientBase : IAsyncClientBase, new()
    {
        // implement a TcpListener to gain access to Active property
        private sealed class ActiveTcpListener : TcpListener
        {
            public ActiveTcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port)
                : base(localaddr, port) { }
            public bool IsActive => Active;
        }

        // our listener object
        private ActiveTcpListener Listener { get; }
        // our clients
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, TClientBase> Clients { get; }

        // construct with a port
        public AsyncServerBase(int port)
        {
            Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TClientBase>();
            Listener = new ActiveTcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        }

        // virtual methods for client action
        public virtual void OnClientConnected(TClientBase client) { }
        public virtual void OnClientDisconnected(TClientBase client, Exception ex) { }

        // start the server
        public void StartListening()
        {
            if(!IsListening)
            {
                Listener.Start();
                Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAcceptedTcpClient, this);
            }
        }

        // check if the server is running
        public bool IsListening =>
            Listener.IsActive;

        // stop the server
        public void StopListening()
        {
            if (IsListening)
            {
                Listener.Stop();
                Parallel.ForEach(Clients, x => x.Value.DetachClient(null));
                Clients.Clear();
            }
        }

        // async callback for when a client wants to connect
        private static void OnAcceptedTcpClient(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            var me = (AsyncServerBase<TClientBase>)res.AsyncState;

            if (!me.IsListening) { return; }

            try
            {
                TcpClient client = null;
                try
                {
                    client = me.Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Warning: unable to accept client:\n{ex}");
                }

                if(client != null)
                {
                    // create a new client
                    var t = new TClientBase();
                    // set up error callbacks
                    t.Error += me.OnClientBaseError;
                    // notify client we have attached
                    t.AttachClient(client);
                    // track the client
                    me.Clients[t.Id] = t;
                    // notify we have a new connection
                    me.OnClientConnected(t);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // if we are still listening, wait for another connection
                if(me.IsListening)
                {
                    me.Listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnAcceptedTcpClient, me);
                }
            }
        }

        // Event callback from a client that an error has occurred
        private void OnClientBaseError(object sender, AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = (TClientBase)sender;
            client.Error -= OnClientBaseError;

            OnClientDisconnected(client, e.Exception);

            client.DetachClient(e.Exception);
            Clients.TryRemove(client.Id, out _);
        }

        // utility method to write data to all clients connected
        public void WriteDataToAllClients(byte[] data)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Clients, x => x.Value.WriteData(data));
        }
    }
}
```

At this point all the basics of running a server have been accounted for. Now for the client that runs on the server:

```
namespace MultiServerExample.Base
{
    public interface IAsyncClientBase
    {
        event EventHandler<AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs> Error;
        void AttachClient(TcpClient client);
        void WriteData(byte[] data);
        void DetachClient(Exception ex);
        string Id { get; }
    }

    public abstract class AsyncClientBase : IAsyncClientBase
    {
        protected virtual int ReceiveBufferSize { get; } = 1024;
        private TcpClient Client { get; set; }
        private byte[] ReceiveBuffer { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler<AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs> Error;
        public string Id { get; }

        public AsyncClientBase()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public void AttachClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            if(ReceiveBuffer != null) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }

            ReceiveBuffer = new byte[ReceiveBufferSize];
            Client = client;

            try
            {
                Client.GetStream().
                    BeginRead(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBufferSize, OnDataReceived, this);
                OnAttachedToServer();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error?.Invoke(this,
                    new AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs(ex, "BeginRead"));
            }
        }

        public void DetachClient(Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                Client.Close();
                OnDetachedFromServer(ex);
            }
            catch { /* intentionally swallow */ }
        
            Client = null;
            ReceiveBuffer = null;
        }

        public virtual void OnDataReceived(byte[] buffer) { }
        public virtual void OnAttachedToServer() { }
        public virtual void OnDetachedFromServer(Exception ex) { }

        public void WriteData(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                Client.GetStream().BeginWrite(data, 0, data.Length, OnDataWrote, this);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Error?.Invoke(this, new AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs(ex, "BeginWrite"));
            }
        }

        private static void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            var me = (AsyncClientBase)iar.AsyncState;

            if(me.Client == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                var bytesRead = me.Client.GetStream().EndRead(iar);
                var buf = new byte[bytesRead];
                Array.Copy(me.ReceiveBuffer, buf, bytesRead);

                me.OnDataReceived(buf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                me.Error?.Invoke(me, new AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs(ex, "EndRead"));
            }
        }

        private static void OnDataWrote(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            var me = (AsyncClientBase)iar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                me.Client.GetStream().EndWrite(iar);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                me.Error?.Invoke(me,
                    new AsyncClientBaseErrorEventArgs(ex, "EndWrite"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all your base code is written. You don't need to change this in any way. You simply implement your own client and server to respond accordingly. For example, here is a basic server implementation:

```
public class MyServer : AsyncServerBase<MyClient>
{
    public MyServer(int port) : base(port)
    {
    }

    public override void OnClientConnected(MyClient client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"* MyClient connected with Id: {client.Id}");
        base.OnClientConnected(client);
    }

    public override void OnClientDisconnected(MyClient client, Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"***** MyClient disconnected with Id: {client.Id} ({ex.Message})");
        base.OnClientDisconnected(client, ex);
    }
}
```

And here is a client that the server above uses for communication:

```
public class MyClient : AsyncClientBase
{
    public override void OnAttachedToServer()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToServer();

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} attached. Waiting for data...");
    }

    public override void OnDataReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        base.OnDataReceived(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} recieved {buffer.Length} bytes. Writing 5 bytes back.");
        WriteData(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    }

    public override void OnDetachedFromServer(Exception ex)
    {
        base.OnDetachedFromServer(ex);

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} detached.");
    }
}
```

And to drive the point home, here is another client that simply would plug in to the same server implementation, but gives it different characteristics:

```
public class MyOtherClient : AsyncClientBase
{
    public override void OnAttachedToServer()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToServer();

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} attached. Writing 4 bytes back.");
        WriteData(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    }

    public override void OnDataReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        base.OnDataReceived(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} recieved {buffer.Length} bytes.");
    }

    public override void OnDetachedFromServer(Exception ex)
    {
        base.OnDetachedFromServer(ex);

        Console.WriteLine($"{Id}: {GetType().Name} detached.");
    }
}
```

As far as using this, here is a small test program that puts it through a stress-test:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var servers = new IAsyncServerBase[]
        {
            new MyServer(50000),
            new MyServer(50001),
            new MyOtherServer(50002)
        };

        foreach (var s in servers)
        {
            s.StartListening();
        }

        RunTestUsingMyServer("1", 89, 50000);
        RunTestUsingMyServer("2", 127, 50001);
        RunTestUsingMyOtherServer("3", 88, 50002);

        Console.Write("Press any key to exit... ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

        foreach (var s in servers)
        {
            s.WriteDataToAllClients(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
            s.StopListening();
        }
    }

    private static void RunTestUsingMyServer(string name, int clientCount, int port)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, clientCount, x =>
        {
            using (var t = new TcpClient())
            {
                t.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
                t.GetStream().Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 0, 5);
                t.GetStream().Read(new byte[512], 0, 512);
                t.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"FINISHED PASS {name} #{x}");
        });
    }

    private static void RunTestUsingMyOtherServer(string name, int clientCount, int port)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, clientCount, x =>
        {
            using (var t = new TcpClient())
            {
                t.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
                t.GetStream().Read(new byte[512], 0, 512);
                t.GetStream().Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 0, 6);
                t.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"FINISHED PASS {name} #{x}");
        });
    }
}
```

If interested, here is the [full source code](https://github.com/sonicmouse/AsyncMultiServer/) you can check out. Hopefully this gets you to where you want to be as it pertains to reusing code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help. You can define a state object with all the information related to every port:

```
public class StateObject
{
    public string Name;
    public Socket Listener;
    public IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint;
    //...

    public StateObject(Socket listener, IPEndPoint endPoint, string name)
    {
        Listener = listener;
        LocalEndPoint = endPoint;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it as you need:

```
    public static void StartListeningMaster()
    {
        string ipAddress = "localhost";
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        IPAddress address = ipHost.AddressList[0];

        StartListening(50000, address, "Main port");
        StartListening(50001, address, "Service port");
        StartListening(50002, address, "Extra");
        //...
    }

    public static void StartListening(int port, IPAddress ipAddress, string name = "")
    {
        //...
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        //...
        StateObject state = new StateObject(listener, localEndPoint);
        listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, state);
        //...
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        //...
        handler.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize,
                     0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        // Always have the info related to every socket
        Socket listener = state.Listener;
        string address = state.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString();
        int port = state.LocalEndPoint.Port;
        string name = state.Name;

        //...
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        //...
        CalculateResult(state);
        //...
        handler.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                             new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        //...
    }
```

The `CalculateResult(state)` method will have all the necessary info to do whatever. This way, you only have one `StartListening()`, one `AcceptCallback()` and one `ReadCallback()` for all the ports to manage.